# flutter: enable contructor-tearoffs not working

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello i'm having this line of code in flutter

```
StreamController<LocationModel> locationController = StreamController<LocationModel>.broadcast;
```

but i'm having erros below:
**This requires the 'constructor-tearoffs' language feature to be enabled.
Try updating your pubspec.yaml to set the minimum SDK constraint to 2.14.0 or higher, and running 'pub get'.dart(ex**

I already update my pubspec.ymal to 2.14.0 but this error still not solved.
any help please.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any experimental compiler feature, you need to add braces at the end:

```
StreamController<LocationModel> locationController = 
                       StreamController<LocationModel>.broadcast(); // <==
```